# error query update mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an query:

```
update customers_training_malaysia
set
     period_id = (select b.id 
                  from customers_training_malaysia a,training_schedules_malaysia b
                  where a.sch_code=b.sch_code order by a,id)
where
     sch_code = (select b.sch_code 
                 from customers_training_malaysia a,training_schedules_malaysia b
                 where a.sch_code = b.sch_code order by a.id)
```

I tried to run following query update, but I get only the error

more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

What shall I do to correct the sql query?

Comment: Maybe try adding a limit 1 to your subquery?

Answer (score 1):

You must get all your subqueries in

```
set [field_name] = ([subquery])
```

and check that this queries returning only one record in results.
That is reason for the error - multiple results in your subqueries

Try this:

```
update customers_training_malaysia
set
     period_id = b.id
where
     sch_code = (select b.sch_code 
                 from customers_training_malaysia a,training_schedules_malaysia b
                 where a.sch_code = b.sch_code order by a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order by a,id)
```

Is this a typo?

`**","**` used it should be `a.id`

And Add from the other answer Below it might be `returning more than one result`, because of `order by` condition i assumed that!